# AVSynchronizedLayer not synchronizing animation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, avfoundation

I'm having issues making the animation use the AVPlayer time instead of the system time. the synchronized layer does not work properly and animations stay synchronized on the system time instead of the player time. I know the player do play. and if I pass CACurrentMediaTime() to the beginTime, the animation start right away as it should when not synchronized.

EDIT

I can see the red square in its final state since the beginning, which mean the animation has reach its end at the beginning because it is synchronized on the system time and not the AVPlayerItem time.

```
    // play composition live in order to modifier
    AVPlayerItem  * playerItem  = [AVPlayerItem  playerItemWithAsset:composition];
    AVPlayer      * player      = [AVPlayer      playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer * playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player   ];
    playerLayer.frame           = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    if (!playerItem) {
        NSLog(@"playerItem empty");
    }
    // dummy time
    playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = totalDuration;
    playerItem.videoComposition       = videoComposition;

    CALayer * aLayer       = [CALayer layer];
    aLayer.frame           = CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 60);
    aLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aLayer.opacity         = 0.f;

    CAKeyframeAnimation * keyframeAnimation2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    keyframeAnimation2.removedOnCompletion   = NO;
    keyframeAnimation2.beginTime             = 0.1;
    keyframeAnimation2.duration              = 4.0;
    keyframeAnimation2.fillMode              = kCAFillModeBoth;
    keyframeAnimation2.keyTimes              = @[@0.0, @1.0];
    keyframeAnimation2.values                = @[@0.f, @1.f];
    NSLog(@"%f current media time", CACurrentMediaTime());

    [aLayer addAnimation:keyframeAnimation2
                  forKey:@"opacity"];

    [self.parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

    AVSynchronizedLayer * synchronizedLayer =
    [AVSynchronizedLayer synchronizedLayerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];


    synchronizedLayer.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    [synchronizedLayer addSublayer:self.parentLayer];
    [playerLayer       addSublayer:synchronizedLayer];
```

Comment: Do you know how to give transition effect between two images during creation of video.If you know how it is possible than please help me..

Comment: play with the alpha of two calayer with the image as their content.

Comment: Where to add the CALayer while create the video from Array of Images.I am creating video from this link.http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/01/create-movie-from-array-of-images/

Comment: in your example you create a movie from image you create an AVAsset using the images you pass to an AVPlayer whereas I simply create CALayer containing images that are added as sublayer to the AVSynchronizedLayer that is like a CALayer only its timeline is synchronized with the time of an AVPlayer playing an AVAsset. AVPlayer->AVAsset AVSynchornizedLayer->CALayer

Comment: Can you give me one example .please

Comment: you need to use the code I posted in the question above animate dismiss for one image and animate appearance in the other using CAKeyframeAnimation on each CALayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was that `AVSynchronizedLayer` doesn't work on the Simulator but works fine on a device.