# Adding cross dissolve effect - iOS video creation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I would like to create a video from a number of images and add a cross dissolve effect between the images.

How can this be done? I know images can be written into a video file, but I don't see where to apply an effect. Should each image be turned into a video and then the videos written into the fill video with the transition effect?

I have searched around and cannot find much information on how this can be done, e.g. how to use AVMutableComposition and if it is viable to create videos consisting of individual images, to then apply the cross dissolve effect.

Any information will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dig around in the bowels of AVFoundation for this, I strongly suggest you [take a look at this presentation, especially starting at slide 74](http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/advanced-media-manipulation-with-av-foundation) Be prepared to do a large amount of work to pull this off...

If you'd like to get down to business several orders of magnitude faster, and don't mind incorporating a 3rd party library, I'd highly [recommend you try GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

You'll find it quite simple to push images into a video and swap them out at will, as well as apply any number of blend filters to the transitions, simply by varying a single mix property of your blend filter over the time your transition happens.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Those slides are pretty much the only info I found on it and it does seem like there is quite a bit of info missing too to fully understand it. I am actually using GPUImage in this app already to apply filters to the images, but I never knew about the transition effects on video. How would the blend filter be used along with writing the video?

Comment: I'd feed two different GPUImagePicture's into your blend (GPUImageDissolveBlend perhaps?) then set up an NSTimer which ticks every 0.1 seconds or so, and increment/decrement the .mix property of the blend filter on each tick. I'd also recycle the GPUImagePicture objects and swap out their images as needed, rather then setup and tear down new GPUImagePictures each time. That will incur a little addTarget/removeTarget startProcessing/stop dance, but should feel seamless to the user.

Comment: Oh, and you'd target both a GPUImageView in your interface and a GPUImageMovieWriter from your dissolveBlend filter. Then you get user playback and recording to file at the same time. Feel free to ping me privately if you run into any snags. contact info at ryancumley dot com

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently doing this right now. To make things short: You need an `AVPlayer` to which you put an `AVPlayerItem` that can be empty. You then need to set the `forwardPlaybackEndTime` of your `AVPlayerItem`to the duration of your animation. You then create an `AVPlayerLayer` that you initiate with your `AVPlayer`. (actually maybe you do not need the `AVPlayerLayer` if you will not put video in your animation. Then the important part, you create an `AVSynchronizedLayer` that your initiate with your previous `AVPlayerItem`. this `AVSynchronizedLayer` and any sublayer it holds will be synchronized with your `AVPlayerItem`. You can then create some simple `CALayer` holding your image (through the `contents` property  and add your `CAKeyframeAnimation` to your layer on the `opacity` property. Now any animation on those sublayers will follow the time of your `AVPlayerItem`. To start the animation, simply call `play`on your `AVPlayer`. That's the theory for playback. If you want to export this animation in an mp4 you will need to use `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` but it's pretty similar.

for code example see [code snippet to create animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707985/avsynchronizedlayer-not-synchronizing-animation)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I have worked out a simpler way for display using UIView + transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: Ill take another look at AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool, but will probably go with GPUImage as Ryan mentioned.

Comment: @NicolasManzini forwardPlaybackEndTime does not work, does it work for you

Comment: indeed it does not work for AVSynchronizedLayer you need to have a player item that has the duration required for your animation or it just won't move.